# How do I produce WE in this diagram?

Tags: memory, sram, rom, 8085

I have designed a memory system that has 10KB ROM followed by 6KB of RAM. The ROM begins at 0000H. I had to use two 4K x 8bit ROMs and one 2K x 8 bit ROM. I also have to use one 2K x 8bit RAM and a 4K x 8bit SRAM. The SRAMs have to have two input controls , CE and OE and WE. Is this diagram correct , how can I produce WE in this diagram?[image]

Comment: Bring it from WR/ on the 8085.

Comment: Is there any reason you haven't considered generating WE in much the same way that you generate OE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a closer look at your diagram, my initial answer was not completely correct.

You need to use another OR gate to logically AND together (all of these signals are active-low) the WR- signal and the IO/M signal from the CPU. The output of this gate goes to all of the RAM WE- inputs. It pulses low only during memory write cycles, and not during I/O write cycles.

The issue here is timing. Your CE- signal is a simple decode from the address bus, so you need to use the WR- signal from the CPU to generate the correct timing for a WE- controlled write cycle to the RAM chips, in order to meet the required address and data setup and hold times. Since you don't want those writes to occur during I/O cycles that happen to have address values that match your RAM addresses, you need the additional gate.

If you can guarantee that no I/O write cycles will have addresses that match RAM addresses (in your firmware<sup>1</sup>), then you can dispense with the gate and tie WR- from the CPU directly to WE- on the RAM chips.

---

<sup>1</sup> In other words, make sure that the upper address bits are zero. This may be inherently true on the 8085 anyway; off the top of my head, I don't remember what appears on the upper address bits during the data transfer cycle of an OUT instruction. (On the Z80, the contents of the A or B register appear there, which can create issues if you're not aware of it.)

---

Followup: I found a [datasheet](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/52062.pdf) that states that the 8-bit I/O address appears on BOTH halves of the address bus during I/O cycles, so you would have to avoid using I/O addresses that match the patterns  xx101xxx, xx110xxx or xx111xxx.